# Доменные имена в зоне .рф и php curl

Tags: php, php-curl

Тут столкнулся с проблемой что curl в php работает по разному в CLI и в Web-сервере с именами в зоне .рф.

Так скрипт:

```
<?php

class Main {
    /**
     * @var array Полученные заголовки
     */
    private $in_header;

    /**
     * @var string Полученный контент
     */
    private $in_body;

    public function __construct ($url) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        if ($curl === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception("curl_init($url) - error");
        }

        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => FALSE,
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($curl, $header) {
                $this->in_header[] = $header;
                return strlen($header);
            },
            CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION  => function ($curl, $body) {
                $this->in_body .= $body;
                return strlen($body);
            }
        );
        if (curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts) === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception("curl_setopt_array() - error: " . curl_error($curl));
        }
        if (curl_exec($curl) === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception("curl_exec() - error: ". curl_error($curl));
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        var_dump($this->in_header);
        echo strlen($this->in_body), PHP_EOL;
    }
}

try {
    echo "PHP: ", phpversion(), PHP_EOL;
    $curl = curl_version();
    echo "cURL: ", $curl['version'], PHP_EOL;

    new Main('http://кто.рф/');
    # new Main('http://ya.ru/');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "$e";
}
```

Нормально отрабатывает из командной строки, и падает с ошибкой `Could not resolve host: кто.рф` в броузере

Проверено на ubuntu 14.04. Пробывал как nginx+php-fpm так и apache+mod_php.

Причем если использовать `http://ya.ru/` в качестве URL поведение Web и CLI одинаковое

Comment: Про idn_to_ascii в курсе, вопрос именно в том что с командной сторки работает, а через броузер - нет

Comment: это точно вики-вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вы в консоли сделаете

```
 $ locale
```

Вы скорее всего увидите:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

И ваш скрипт  - отработает!

Если вы в скрипте вставите:

```
echo setlocale  (LC_ALL,"0");
```

Вы скорее всего увидите:

```
С
```

Вставьте перед вызовом своего класса:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF8");
```

И у вас все получится!

Comment: Да, дело было именно в настройках локали, причем не обязательно ru_RU.UTF-8, достаточно любой utf-ной локали например: en_US.UTF-8 вполне себе работает.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

http://2ip.ru/punycode/
Попробуй сюдой преобразовать и отрезолвить

Comment: Про punycode - в курсе, именно этим и занимается idn_to_ascii, см. http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php